# SQL Server uses only 1 CPU of 4 available

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've two machines with SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 with default configuration settings for CPU usage.

I'm using this query on my work machine:

```
SELECT cpu_count
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info
```

It returns "4", which is true.

The same query on production machine returns "1" (that machine has 4 processors too).
There's no additional CPU usage settings in both cases, except defaults.

Production machine is a virtual machine, which, possibly, was reconfigured after SQL Server installation.

Is there any way to reconfigure SQL Server for using of 4 processors?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server Express is limited to 1 CPU only

(to add more details it's limited to one socket or four cores, whichever is less)

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "CPU". The actual [restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645993.aspx) is "Limited to lesser of 1 Socket or 4 cores"

Comment: Do you mean physical CPU or cores?

Comment: @EdHarper: thanks for the link, I think, the problem is that on my work machine I have 1 CPU with 4 cores, and on production - 4 CPUs.

Comment: It is worth adding that you may be able to configure your hypervisor to present a single socket to your server, but with multiple cores.  More details here: http://serverfault.com/questions/385079/are-vcpu-the-same-as-1-socket-or-a-single-core and also here http://serverfault.com/questions/422805/do-hyper-v-guests-see-multiple-cpus-sockets-or-multiple-cpu-cores-when-assigne